# Valid linux command rejected in awk script

Tags: command-line, scripts, awk, regex

The test command is:

```
$ if echo 'abcd' | grep  -q '[a-zA-Z]'; then echo 'alpha'; fi
```

From terminal I get 'alpha' as expected.

But when I put the command in text file akpl.awk and run with

```
$ awk -f akpl.awk sppl.txt
```

I get error message.

I am trying to count up alphabetical entries in field 5 of each line in sppl.txt
so 'abcd' would normally be replaced by $5

By the way is this a sensible way to check strings with regex patterns?

Comment: You seem to be trying to run shell commands with awk?  Maybe you need to read up on [what an interpreter is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands inside an awk script must be valid awk commands, rather than valid shell commands.

Although it does have mechanisms for executing external commands via the `system()` function, or the use of `getline` from a pipe or co-process, these are used rather rarely. For simple text processing tasks, awk's built-in capabilities are usually enough.

In particular, GNU awk (`gawk`) - which is the default in current versions of Ubuntu - has regex matching capabilities roughly equivalent to POSIX Extended Regular Expression (ERE) syntax, so that you can usually avoid using `grep`. For example, given

```
$ cat myscript.awk 
$5 ~ /[a-zA-Z]/ {print "Line " FNR ": alpha"}
```

and

```
$ cat file.txt
A B C D E F G H
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
a b c d e f g h
```

then

```
$ awk -f myscript.awk file.txt
Line 1: alpha
Line 3: alpha
```